# Why is this JavaScript program not working?

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure this out.  It is a problem with the quizResult variable but I'm not sure how to get the program to do what I want.  I also tired += 1 and the program wouldn't run at all.
Please help.

```js
//Five question quiz using prompt, result at the end, and will be ranked

/*Questions*/
var question1 = prompt("What does 2 + 2 equal?");
var question2 = prompt("Name one of the five greatest rappers of all time");
var question3 = prompt("Fill in the blank- I'll be ____");
var question4 = prompt("What programming language are we using?");
var question5 = prompt("Are you alive?");

/*Counter*/
var quizResult = 0;

/*Conditionals*/
if(parseInt(question1) === 4){
  var quizResult = quizResult +1;
}
if(question2.toLowerCase === "dylon"){
  var quizResult = quizResult +1;
}
if(question3.toLowerCase === "back"){
  var quizResult = quizResult +1;
}
if(question4.toLowerCase === "javascript"){
  var quizResult = quizResult +1;
}
if(question5.toLowerCase === "yes"){
  var quizResult = quizResult +1;
}

/*Display Reslut to user*/
if(quizResult === 5){
  document.write("You answered " + quizResult + " correctly.  You recieve the gold crown.");
}else if(quizResult >= 3 && quizResult <= 4){
  document.write("You answered " + quizResult + " correctly.  You recieve the silver crown.");
}else if(quizResult >= 1 && quizResult <= 2){
  document.write("You answered " + quizResult + " correctly.  You recieve the bronze crown.");
}else{
  document.write("You answered " + quizResult + " correctly. Congratulations, you are not that bright.");
}
```

Comment: Replace the entire line with `quizResult++`, don't redefine the variable every time.

Comment: `.toLowerCase` is a function! use it as `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it there are way too many things wrong to explain them all, you need to go back and get a good JavaScript tutorial. This is beyond **too broad**.

Comment: I found the problem .toLowerCase needs to have parenthesis added. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that toLowerCase() is a function so you need to call it as such.

The other problem is you don't need to type var anytime you call a variable, but this is not causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing a strict-equality comparison with the function toLowerCase, rather than comparing the result of the toLowerCase() function, i.e.:

```
if(question4.toLowerCase === "javascript")
```

versus

```
if(question4.toLowerCase() === "javascript")
```

In this case, you may just want to use the `==` operator to check for equality, meaning the result of `question1` would match both "5" and 5 (and therefore, you wouldn't need to use `parseInt` if you didn't want to).